# Remove self loops and vertex with no edges

Tags: r, igraph

I am constructing a gene network. I have a two column data frame which i converted into and adjacency matrix and use it in igraph. The problem is i have genes that have self loops, I want to get rid of self loops and then get rid of the vertices that have no edge (isolated maybe) from the network. I have tried a few things but somehow they do not work. My code is

```
 InnatedGraph <- graph.data.frame(innate,directed=FALSE)
 V(InnatedGraph)$label.cex = 0.4
 plot(InnatedGraph,vertex.label=V(InnatedGraph)$symbol, vertex.size=5)
```

innate is my two column data frame. I have tried the degree function to remove vertices with 0 degree but i guess unfortunately it does not work (maybe becoz the self loop genes have degree 1).

```
bad.vs<-V(InnatedGraph)[degree(InnatedGraph) == 0] 
clean <-delete.vertices(InnatedGraph, bad.vs)
```

I tried using another function from package BioNet "rmSelfLoops" with the help of which i was able to remove the self loop edges but then still unable to remove the vertices with no edges.

```
test<-rmSelfLoops(InnatedGraph)
```

I will also include a picture of my network just to make it easier to understand.[image]

Comment: Before converting to igraph object, remove rows from the dataframe where `fromColumn` and `toColumns` are the same value?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: @zx8754 Thank you so much , i would try that !

Comment: @zx8754, can you please help me with the row removal, i searched alot and found removal of duplicated rows but not exactly what i want.

Comment: Provide example data, please. Then I am sure @lukeA can address your problem better.

Comment: For posterity, dropping rows that represent self-edges may inadvertently drop isolates. It is safer to leave the edgelist intact and use `simplify` as mentioned by @lukeA.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Consider this example graph and its two subsets/modifications:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)
g <- random.graph.game(10, p.or.m = 3, "gnm") + edge(7,7)
coords <- layout.auto(g)
par(mfrow = c(1,3))
plot(g, layout = coords)
plot(simplify(g), layout = coords) # remove loops and multiple edges
plot(delete.vertices(simplify(g), degree(g)==0)) # additionally delete isolated nodes
```

[image]

---

Using OP's sample data from the comment:

```
df <- read.csv(header=F, row.names = 1, stringsAsFactors=F, text='"53","ENSG00000175104","ENSG00000175104"
"54","ENSG00000174775","ENSG00000175104"
"55","ENSG00000032688","ENSG00000027164"
"56","ENSG00000175104","ENSG00000140968"
"57","ENSG00000027164","ENSG00000041515"
"58","ENSG00000027164","ENSG00000025498"')
library(igraph)
( dfclean <- subset(df, V2!=V3) ) # remove rows where source==target
#                V2              V3
# 54 ENSG00000174775 ENSG00000175104
# 55 ENSG00000032688 ENSG00000027164
# 56 ENSG00000175104 ENSG00000140968
# 57 ENSG00000027164 ENSG00000041515
# 58 ENSG00000027164 ENSG00000025498
par(mfrow = c(1,3))
plot(graph_from_data_frame(df), edge.arrow.size = .5) # orig
plot(simplify(graph_from_data_frame(df)), edge.arrow.size = .5) # same as
plot(graph_from_data_frame(dfclean), edge.arrow.size = .5) # this one
```

Comment: So i have a data frame like this

Comment: "53","ENSG00000175104","ENSG00000175104"
"54","ENSG00000174775","ENSG00000175104"
"55","ENSG00000032688","ENSG00000027164"
"56","ENSG00000175104","ENSG00000140968"
"57","ENSG00000027164","ENSG00000041515"
"58","ENSG00000027164","ENSG00000025498"                                       you can see the first row the same gene has an edge with it self , how can i delete this row from my data frame?

Comment: @Saad: Create the graph `g`, use `simplify(g)`.

Comment: @lukeA you shouldn't use `simplify(g)` and `degree(g)==0` inside `delete.vertices` in one call, because it wouldn't remove vertices that had only self loop. You should either modify it to something like:  `delete.vertices(simplify(g), degree(simplify(g))==0)` or do it in two steps

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `graph_from_adjacency_matrix` to convert your adjacency matrix into a graph and set the argument `diag=F`.

That should get rid of the self-loops.