# Remove self-loop in visNetwork

Tags: r, visnetwork

I want to remove the self-loop in *visNetwork*, how can I do it?

```r
library(visNetwork)
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3)
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))
visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%")
```

[image]

I tried to add the following code, but it still did not work.

```r
edges$value = 1
edges$value = ifelse(edges$from == edges$to, 0, edges$value)
```

Comment: Remove them before plotting? `visNetwork(nodes, edges[ edges$from != edges$to, ], width = "100%")`

Comment: Related post using igraph: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40086031/680068

Comment: @zx8754, Your solution works very well, and it is very simple. How can I accept your answer?

Comment: Posted as answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can remove edges where `from` is same as `to` before plotting:

```
library(visNetwork)

visNetwork(nodes = nodes, edges = edges[ edges$from != edges$to, ])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try `simplify` from `igraph` before calling `visNetwork`

```
library(visNetwork)
library(igraph)

edges %>%
  graph_from_data_frame() %>%
  simplify() %>%
  toVisNetworkData() %>%
  {
    visNetwork(.$nodes, .$edges, width = "100%")
  }
```

which produces a graph like

[image]